# How can I move out my question to another SE

Tags: discussion

I have asked this question in this SE https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34274/what-is-the-internal-mechanism-of-neural-network-for-cloud4cancer . I asked here because its the first SE I seen in the science section (footer). but when I think about it this question is more related to [programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [CS SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). How can I move my question to those SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention and state that you want to the question to be migrated to another site. The moderators then consider the request and if they decide it is suitable they migrate it. If they decide that it is not clear if it is suitable for the other site they may reject your request.

Alternatively you can delete your question here yourself by clicking on the delete button under your question and then repost it on the other site.